# How to disable Windows 10 Mail app mail count in tile and lock screen

Tags: email, windows-10, modern-ui

Windows 10 mail app shows the total number of mail at the metro tile and lock screen, which feels weird for me. I think showing unread number would be much better. How can I disable the count or change it to unread count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as below:

- Search 'Lock Screen Settings' in search windows box
- Under 'choose an option to show detailed status' and 'choose an option to show quick status' select 'Non' for all those apps for which you do not want to show any update
- For example, to disable email count notification, you can select None for Email app, and to disable message count, you can select None for Messaging app.

I only kept the clock enabled, and everything else is disabled.

This is such a relief!